# looping through json data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556476/ajax-coldfusion-cfc-json-hello-world), but I thought I'd reword it a bit differently in order to make myself more clear.
I have this json coming back from a $.ajax call:

{"COLUMNS":["PERSONID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME"],"DATA":[[1001,"Scott","Wimmer"],[1002,"Phillip","Senn"],[1003,"Paul","Nielsen"]]}

Q: In JavaScript, how do I parse through it to make a table such as:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>PersonID</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1001</td>
   <td>Scott</td>
   <td>Wimmer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1002</td>
   <td>Phillip</td>
   <td>Senn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1003</td>
   <td>Paul</td>
   <td>Nielsen</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var yourJson = {"COLUMNS":["PERSONID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME"],"DATA":[[1001,"Scott","Wimmer"],[1002,"Phillip","Senn"],[1003,"Paul","Nielsen"]];    
var table = '<table>';

table += '<thead><tr><th>' + yourJson.COLUMNS.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr></thead>';
table += '<tbody>';

for (var i=0;i<yourJson.DATA.length;i++) {
  table += '<tr><td>' + yourJson.DATA[i].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
};

table += '</tbody>';
table += '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Matt Lunn!  This answer has really opened the flood gates for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use client side templating engine such as [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) or [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) to achieve it easily.